# jumpstart - ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, minitest

I’m getting the following when running `rails test` on a brand new jumpstart/gorails installation and blank database:-

```
DRb::DRbRemoteError: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "index_users_on_email"
DETAIL:  Key (email)=() already exists.
 (ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique)
```

In my schema, I have the following on Users which is causing the above:-

`t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true`

It seems the error is telling me there’s an existing record (a User?) but the db is blank, so I don’t understand why this is happening?

Comment: Do you currently allow NULL values on the email address? If so, you may be inserting multiple records with a NULL email address. Toss is presence validation on the model to make sure you have an email address, and see if the problem changes to a validation error.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle in this way:
I had a similar issue while creating user.
I fixed in this way.

```
begin
   User.where(email: "abc@gmail.com").first_or_create(email:"abc@gmail.com", name: "name of user", other fields)
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
   retry
end
```

Comment: Would it be a good idea to have a count for the retries incase the race conditions cause an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have any blank entries in `test/fixtures/users.yml`. If so, remove them, or give them non-null email addresses.

I've not used jumpstart, but from a quick scan of their website, I'm guessing that it's using Devise, which creates two blank fixtures and will make tests balk if you've added in a unique index on any field.